# Error when checking out a SVN project in android studio (Windows)

Tags: android, windows, svn, android-studio, svn-checkout

My company's using a SVN repository to store an android project, on which we already have 2 developers working (both Linux users).

The problem is that now I need to checkout the project as well, but on a Windows computer. When I try to checkout the project, android studio shows up kinda like a general error message: 
"Cannot load supported formats: Exit code: -1073741515, Error: , Timeout: false"

I've checked through the web as well as some SO answers and none of them is a problem like this... I've tried installing a third party SVN client (even though android studio is supposed to have an SVN client on its own), checked the repository's permissions pretty much everything I could think of...

I appreciate any hints on this.

Comment: Could it be a line ending problem?

Comment: -1073741515 is actually STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND of c++ compiler. Sounds like not so easy to catch issue.

What is the result of check-out process with third party SVN client (also, which one did you use)?

Comment: I've installed Tortoise, checking out using it's own UI works just fine :/